# asp.net identity with custom password hasher

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity

so I'm trying to get asp.net to work with a custom passwordhasher.
the registration works when I change the hasher with the following code

```
IPasswordHasher hasher = new CustomPassword();

UserManager.PasswordHasher = hasher;
```

but the sign in method keep saying my credentials don't exist when using the following code for the login method in the acountcontroller

```
IPasswordHasher hasher = new CustomPassword();

SignInManager.UserManager.PasswordHasher = hasher;
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using your own password hasher instead of the built in ones?

Comment: The built in password hasher does what it is required to do.. why would you invent something which works so well?

Comment: I have to do a sign in from another application, so using the default hasher is going to be difficult

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue ?

Comment: @Izzy Sometimes you need to match the password hashing algorithm from a legacy system in order to provide a seamless transition to the new system...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and the answer was not obvious.
This was done in .Net6 but I believe should be the same for whatever version you   are using.

You need to make sure you add the passwordhasher before the call to AddIdentity

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, PasswordHasherService>();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

SigninManager will then use the password hasher you defined instead of the default one.